# firebase url saves Wrong url addres in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```java
storageReference.child("uploads").child(id).child(filename).putFile(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        String url = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        //store the data to real time DB
                        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
                        final String pdfname = name.getText().toString();
                        final String  qeditname=name.getText().toString();
                       // reference.child("PDF").child(id).child(filename1+"name").setValue(pdfname);
                        reference.child("PDF").child(id).child(filename1+qeditname).setValue(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Upload succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

[image: database]

this is my code...what is the problem in

`String url = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();`

here the url save "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@41c431b8" it is wrong i want to save like
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com....................."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

`getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString()`